# Revoke alter permissions on service account

Tags: sql-server

I had run the following statements to grant alter permissions on specific tables for the service account

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON [PartyMsci] TO  "INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de";
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON [Product] TO  "INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de";
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON [SimpleIndustryPICS8] TO  "INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de";
```

How do I remove these permissions ?

Comment: Run the same script with the original table owner (dbo?) instead of the service account.

Comment: If I run the same script how is it is going to remove the permissions

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean

Comment: `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON [PartyMsci] TO  dbo;`

Comment: I get the following message Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.

Comment: Do I need to login as the service account user and then run those permissions

Comment: If I login as service account and run the commands i get error that you do not have permissions

Comment: I see Max already provided a script to change ownership to the schema owner.

Comment: If you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql), you'll understand that this command changes the ownership of an object. As the owner of the object, you can perform certain actions. However, once you are no longer the owner, you can no longer perform any actions that you could only perform because you were the owner.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reset the ownership of the object by executing the following:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON PartyMsci TO SCHEMA OWNER;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON Product TO SCHEMA OWNER;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SimpleIndustryPICS8 TO SCHEMA OWNER;
```

You can determine who the current owner is for objects in the database using this query:

```
SELECT ObjectName = o.name
    , ObjectOwner = CASE WHEN dp.name IS NOT NULL THEN dp.name ELSE so.name END
FROM sys.objects o
    LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON o.principal_id = dp.principal_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals so ON s.principal_id = so.principal_id
ORDER BY o.name;
```

The [Microsoft Docs on `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql) makes this note:

> If the target entity is not a database and the entity is being transferred to a new owner, all permissions on the target will be dropped.

As a result, you should analyze the required permissions on those objects before you change the owner via `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`, and re-apply appropriate permissions once you have changed the owner.